How can I mount this special disk? (.vmdk format, bootable but cound not mount...)
I got a virtual disk from a CyberSecurity vendor, I want to check the files on it.
When I set my virtual machine boot from this disk, it can normally boot.
I want to check the files on it, so I attach this disk to my Rocky linux VM.
But when I try to mount this disk, I got this:
[root@localhost ~]# mount /dev/vxda1 /mnt/
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/vxda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

And fdisk -lresult seems no partition is bootable, and could not show the file system type:
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l /dev/vxda
Disk /dev/vxda: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Disk model: VMware Virtual S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/vxda1          8192  270335  262144  128M 83 Linux
/dev/vxda2        270336  794623  524288  256M 83 Linux

Other commands like file -sL, lsblkalso cound not show the file system:
[root@localhost ~]# file -sL /dev/vxda
/dev/vxda: DOS/MBR boot sector

[root@localhost ~]# file -sL /dev/vxda1
/dev/vxda1: data

[root@localhost ~]# file -sL /dev/vxda2
/dev/vxda2: data
[root@localhost ~]# blkid /dev/vxda1 

[root@localhost ~]# lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
vxda                                                                                          
├─vxda1                                                                                       
├─vxda2                                                                                       
                                                                                      


[root@localhost ~]# lsblk -no FSTYPE /dev/vxda





[root@localhost ~]# lsblk -no FSTYPE /dev/vxda1

[root@localhost ~]# lsblk -no name,fstype
vxda         
├─vxda1      
├─vxda2      
    


The only command which can provide something is fsck, it shows this may be an ext2 format partition:
[root@localhost ~]# fsck -N /dev/vxda
fsck from util-linux 2.37.4
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext2 (1) -- /dev/vxda] fsck.ext2 /dev/vxda 
[root@localhost ~]# fsck -N /dev/vxda1 
fsck from util-linux 2.37.4
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext2 (1) -- /dev/vxda1] fsck.ext2 /dev/vxda1

But mount with -t ext2 still not work:
[root@localhost ~]# mount -t ext2 /dev/vxda1 /mnt/
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/vxda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
[root@localhost ~]#

The first 512 bytes of this disk:
[root@localhost tmp]# xxd /dev/vxda|more
00000000: eb63 9000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .c..............
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0080 0100 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 fffa 9090 f6c2 8074 05f6 c270  ...........t...p
00000070: 7402 b280 ea79 7c00 0031 c08e d88e d0bc  t....y|..1......
00000080: 0020 fba0 647c 3cff 7402 88c2 52be 807d  . ..d|<.t...R..}
00000090: e817 01be 057c b441 bbaa 55cd 135a 5272  .....|.A..U..ZRr
000000a0: 3d81 fb55 aa75 3783 e101 7432 31c0 8944  =..U.u7...t21..D
000000b0: 0440 8844 ff89 4402 c704 1000 668b 1e5c  .@.D..D.....f..\
000000c0: 7c66 895c 0866 8b1e 607c 6689 5c0c c744  |f.\.f..`|f.\..D
000000d0: 0600 70b4 42cd 1372 05bb 0070 eb76 b408  ..p.B..r...p.v..
000000e0: cd13 730d f6c2 800f 84d8 00be 8b7d e982  ..s..........}..
000000f0: 0066 0fb6 c688 64ff 4066 8944 040f b6d1  .f....d.@f.D....
00000100: c1e2 0288 e888 f440 8944 080f b6c2 c0e8  .......@.D......
00000110: 0266 8904 66a1 607c 6609 c075 4e66 a15c  .f..f.`|f..uNf.\
00000120: 7c66 31d2 66f7 3488 d131 d266 f774 043b  |f1.f.4..1.f.t.;
00000130: 4408 7d37 fec1 88c5 30c0 c1e8 0208 c188  D.}7....0.......
00000140: d05a 88c6 bb00 708e c331 dbb8 0102 cd13  .Z....p..1......
00000150: 721e 8cc3 601e b900 018e db31 f6bf 0080  r...`......1....
00000160: 8ec6 fcf3 a51f 61ff 265a 7cbe 867d eb03  ......a.&Z|..}..
00000170: be95 7de8 3400 be9a 7de8 2e00 cd18 ebfe  ..}.4...}.......
00000180: 4752 5542 2000 4765 6f6d 0048 6172 6420  GRUB .Geom.Hard 
00000190: 4469 736b 0052 6561 6400 2045 7272 6f72  Disk.Read. Error
000001a0: 0d0a 00bb 0100 b40e cd10 ac3c 0075 f4c3  ...........<.u..
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0082  ................
000001c0: 0300 83d3 0310 0020 0000 0000 0400 00d3  ....... ........
000001d0: 0410 8376 0531 0020 0400 0000 0800 0076  ...v.1. .......v
000001e0: 0631 83bb 0972 0020 0c00 0000 1000 00bb  .1...r. ........
000001f0: 0a72 8315 5005 0020 1c00 00e0 2300 55aa  .r..P.. ....#.U.

Anybody have ideas, what can i do next?
Thanks a lot!

Take s Look Here If Something is available https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327728/mounting-vmdk-disk-image#30201153

@nobody Thanks for your replay, but with cmd LIBGUESTFS_BACKEND=direct guestmount -a disk1.vmdk -m /dev/sda2 --ro /mnt/ still hit the same error message: libguestfs: error: mount_options: mount exited with status 32: mount: /sysroot: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Finally I find out the reason.
fdisk -l shows the first partition start at sector 8192.
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l /dev/vxda
Disk /dev/vxda: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Disk model: VMware Virtual S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/vxda1          8192  270335  262144  128M 83 Linux

But at sector 8192 (8192*512=4194304 bytes position), there is no superblock found (The Superblock is always located at byte 1024 from the beginning of the volume and is exactly 1024 bytes in length, so the postion we check should be 4195328):
[root@localhost grub]# xxd -d /dev/vxda|grep -C5 04195328 
04195248: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
04195264: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
04195280: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
04195296: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
04195312: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
04195328: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
04195344: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
04195360: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
04195376: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
04195392: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
04195408: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................

Generally, in normal linux disk, the first sector of a partition is at sector 2048 (2048*512=1048576 bytes position), so I check the data at 1049600 (2048 * 512 + 1024), and I found it maybe an EXT2 partition (0x53,0xef at 56-57 is ext2 signature):
01049600: 401f 0000 007d 0000 4006 0000 9e3f 0000  @....}..@....?..
01049616: 0f1e 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
01049632: 0020 0000 0020 0000 d007 0000 ad55 a066  . ... .......U.f
01049648: ad55 a066 0200 ffff 53ef 0100 0100 0000  .U.f....S.......
01049664: f396 a856 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000  ...V............
01049680: 0000 0000 0b00 0000 8000 0000 3c00 0000  ............<...

It’s speculated that this is deliberately done by the manufacturer out of safety considerations.
After change the "Start Sector" from 8192 to 2048 at DPT:
000001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0082  ................
000001c0: 0300 83d3 0310 0020 0000 0000 0400 00d3  ....... ........

change 1c6 - 1c7 from 0020(8192) to 0008(2048) like this:
000001c0: 0300 83d3 0310 0008 0000 0000 0400 00d3  ....... ........

Then remount the partition, succssfully!
[root@localhost ~]# mount /dev/vxda1 /mnt/
[root@localhost ~]# cd /mnt
[root@localhost mnt]# ls
grub  krnl-xxx-yyy  lost+found


A vmdk file is not a raw disk image; you can't just attach it to a VM and expect it to work.
However you can convert it
eg
qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw image.vmdk image.img

Now you should(!) have a raw file and things like fdisk -l image.img should show the partition table.  This can then either be mounted (e.g. using kpartx to create loopback entries in /dev/mapper that you can then mount) or attach to a VM.

Thanks for you replay! I tried those steps but still can not work:
[root@rocky tmp]# kpartx -a /root/tmp/image.img 
[root@rocky tmp]# ls -l /dev/mapper/
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Jul 20 17:43 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Jul 20 21:21 loop0p1 -> ../dm-1
...
...
[root@rocky tmp]# mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/loop0p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.



Since when a raw image is the only kind of image that can be attached to a VM?
